# SpringMVC - request syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have the following page (Spring NVC) which works fine:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Replace Cards</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Replace Cards</h3>
        <br/><br/>
        Give the numbers of cards in your hand you want replace and hit the button<br/>
        Valid numbers: 1 to 5, numbers must be separated by space<br/>
        #NEW CODE#
        <br/>
        <sf:form action="execReplaceCards" commandName="cards">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><sf:input path="playerName" type="text"/></td>
                    <td><sf:input path="numbers" type="text"/></td>
                    <td><input value="Replace" type="submit"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </sf:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

until I add the following piece of code before the form tag 
(marked above as #NEW CODE#):

```
Here is your hand:
        <br/><br/>
        <c:out value="Hand name: "/>&nbsp;
        <c:out value="${hand.name}"/><br/>
        <c:forEach var="card" items="${hand.cards.card}">
            <c:out value="Card:[${card.suit} : ${card.rank}]"/><br/>
        </c:forEach>
        <c:out value="${hand.value}"/>
        <br/>
```

This snippet doesn't do anything except displaying the players hand for reference but since I add this part I've got request syntactically incorrect error. Request never reaches the controller. What's wrong, why is it happening?

Comment: I actually meant that the page appears fine but submit button doesn't work when I add the snippet in question

Comment: Are you you sure the loop shouldn't be  <c:forEach var="card" items="${hand.cards}">

Comment: Yes I am sure, that unfortunate structure: **hand.cards.card** actually points correct list. This is not an issue here, this part works fine and also show up on screen. The problem is that the SUBMIT button cease working